# How to add private github repository as Composer dependency

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, composer-php

I have the following in my Laravel 5.1 projects composer.json to add a public github repository as a dependency.

```
...    
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "myVendorName/my_private_repo",
      "version": "1.2.3",
      "source": {
        "type" : "git",
        "url" : "git://github.com/myVendorName/my_private_repo.git",
        "reference" : "master"
      },
      "dist": {
        "url": "https://github.com/myVendorName/my_private_repo/archive/master.zip",
        "type": "zip"
      }
    }
  }
],
"require": {
     ....
    "myVendorName/my_private_repo": "*",
},
...
```

This works as long as the repository is public. Now I've set this repository to private. The git credentials I use for pulling/pushing to 'my_private_repo' are the one of a colaborator of the project. How can I achieve that composer pulls from that private repository when I run **composer update** or **composer install**?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Work with private repositories at GitHub and BitBucket:

**JSON**

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client.

[Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories)

Comment: Can anyone clarify what exactly `The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client` means?

Comment: One way to check that the above example composer.json would work, would be first to ensure that a command like `git clone git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git` works on the machine which composer will be running on. For me that clone command would not work as I usually use SSH Aliases like `git clone git@my-alias:vendor/my-private-repo.git`

Comment: Just a note that the property referenced in `require` refers to the package name (i.e. the name in the `composer.json` of the dependency) not the repository name, which may be different.

Comment: Does it always have to be `dev-master` in require directive?

Comment: @SamAnthony He's indicating that you're going to have access to any keys git can see, and therefore any repos that require those keys.  If you can clone the repo with git, composer can pull it into vendor/.

Comment: @Dennis "dev-master" simply refers to the master branch, you could require "dev-staging" or any other branch. You can also require tagged commits on the package repo, e.g. a git tag named "2.0.1" can then be required using composer version constraints like so: "vendor/my-private-repo": "~2.0.0". https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints

Comment: Does this still work? I have my ssh keys in place and can cone the repo without issue but whenever I run composer install, I get asked for a token.

Comment: @clueless I had the same issue. I forgot to use the -n flag. I added it to my require command and it worked.

Answer (score 38):

I hope my answer does not come too late as i just learned this my self.

### Generating a ssh key

You can generate n+1 ssh keys with ssh-keygen command. Make sure you do this in the server!

```
➜  ~ cd ~/.ssh
➜  .ssh ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): repo1
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in repo1.
Your public key has been saved in repo1.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:EPc79FoaidfN0/PAsjSAZdomex2J1b/4zUR6Oj7IV2o user@laptop
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|      . . o ..   |
|       o B o ..  |
|      . + B o  . |
|       . * B = .o|
|        S B O B+o|
|         o B =.+*|
|          o....Bo|
|            o E.o|
|             +.o |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

After using the ssh-keygen command you will be prompted for the filename and passphrase. You need a key for each private repository you're going to use as composer dependency. In this example the repo1 is the filename.

> Make sure you leave the passphrase and confirmation empty.

### Configuring the ssh to pick up the correct key

In servers ~/.ssh/config file you can assign an alias for each GitHub repository. Otherwise composer tries to use the default id_rsa.

```
Host repo1
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo1
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host repo2
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo2
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

### Configuring Composer

In projects composer.json file you need to add the repositories you want as dependencies:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "repo1:YourAccount/repo1.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "repo2:YourAccount/repo2.git"
    }
],
```

repo1 and repo2 are the aliases you created in ~/ssh/config file. The full GitHub ssh url for repo1 would be:

git@github.com:YourAccount/repo1.git

And now you should be set for good. You can now require your dependencies:

`composer require youraccount/repo1 -n`

`composer require youraccount/repo2 -n`

> NB! When using GitHub repositories as composer dependencies you always need to add -n to each composer command.

Comment: Where to store the keys on a windows 10 machine?

Comment: sorry, i am a linux user.

Comment: @GeoffSalmon Typically keys get stored in your users directory. Example: C:\Users\YOURUSER\.ssh

Comment: Hello. I'm from 2021. I struggled all day until I found your answer. Why doesn't it work without `-n`?

Comment: Why do I need a separate ssh key for every repository? Can't I use the default id_rsa?

Answer (score 7):

**1. Point to the Git repository**

Update composer.json and add a repository:

```
    "repositories":[
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:vendor/secret.git"
      }
    ]
```

**2. Create an SSH key**

Create an SSH Key on the machine on which you want to install the package.

If you are working on a development machine, you probably want to add the SSH key to your GitHub/BitBucket/GitLab account. This gives access to all private repositories that your account has access to.

> For more information on how to add Github, Bitbucket or Gitlab SSH keys, see this [excellent article](https://barryvanveen.nl/blog/55-installing-a-private-package-with-composer)

In case you are configuring a deployment server, it would be better to configure an access key or deploy key. An access key only provides access to a single repository and thus allows for more specific access management.

**3. Run composer**

Now just composer require or `composer install` the package as usual.

Comment: I also had to run `composer require vendor/secret` to install the package

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can let composer ensure you leave valid json in your composer.json file, using a command like this to configure your repository:

```
composer config repositories.my_alias \
    '{"type": "vcs", \
      "url": "git@git.example.com:my_repo.git", \
      "ssh2": { "username": "git", \
                "privkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa", \
                "pubkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" \
              } \
    }'
```

**NOTE:**  I have not tested using the '' line continuance token inside the quoted attributes.  My successful tests involved running this all on a single line.  But I find that this formatting is easier for humans to understand in this format.

**FURTHER NOTE:** This command will continue to throw errors until your `ssh-keygen` key-pair is in place and your public key is configured on the repo, as described in other answers to this question.

Running this command results is the following entry in my composer.json file:

```
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "my_alias": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.example.com:my_repo.git",
            "ssh2": {
                "username": "git",
                "privkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa",
                "pubkey_file": "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
            }
        }
    },
```

This usage is documented here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#config

Answer (score 0):

You can also add it to the `composer.json` file via the command line:

```
composer config repositories.repo-name vcs https://github.com/<orgname or username>/repo-name
```

For example:

Repository: https://github.com/chapagain/auto-currency-switcher-2

```
composer config repositories.auto-currency-switcher vcs https://github.com/chapagain/auto-currency-switcher-2
```

Running the above command will add the following to the `composer.json` file:

```
repositories": {
    "auto-currency-switcher": {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/chapagain/auto-currency-switcher-2"
    },
```

The type can be `vcs` or we can also be specific by using type as `git`.

> The VCS driver to be used is detected automatically based on the URL. However, should you need to specify one for whatever reason, you can use `bitbucket`, `github`, `gitlab`, `perforce`, `fossil`, `git`, `svn` or `hg` as the repository type instead of `vcs`.
>
> [https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#types:~:text=The%20VCS%20driver,vcs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#types:%7E:text=The%20VCS%20driver,vcs)

After that, you can run the following command to install the module.

```
composer require <orgname or username>/repo:dev-<branchname>
```

For our example above, we will run the following command to install the module:

```
composer require chapagain/magento2-autocurrency
```

Because the name of the module in the `composer.json` file is `chapagain/magento2-autocurrency`: https://github.com/chapagain/auto-currency-switcher-2/blob/master/composer.json#L2C12-L2C43