# Could not resolve hostname with composer and private repository on gitlab

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I want to use a private git repository with composer, I add the private repository like

```
{
    type: "git", 
    url: [git@host:port]:directory/subdirectory/repo. git"
}
```

On my Mac it's working fine, but on the server (Debian) I'm getting `could not resolve hostname host:port]:` when it's trying to do a git clone.

But the hostname ist reachable. It seems it doesn't like the syntax `[git@host:port]:`

I would use type: gitlab, but composer has problems with subdirectories in gitlab.

Comment: Refer to this stackoverflow post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619393/how-to-add-private-github-repository-as-composer-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619393/how-to-add-private-github-repository-as-composer-dependency)

Comment: Hey, thanks, but this is not helping. I've done this and it's working in my Mac. But on Debian I get an error message could not resolve hostname.

Comment: are you using IP address as `@host` ?, sometimes system name given same error to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem will be the port - you could try via http - if using standard ports is not an option

```
"url" : "http://user:password@host:port/directory/subdirectory/repo.git",
```

i guess you have tested this notation as well:

```
"url" : "ssh://git@host:port/directory/subdirectory/repo.git",
```

Comment: Thank you, the right syntax was `"url" : "ssh://git@host:port/directory/subdirectory/repo.git",`. Sometimes things can be so easy :D I don't know why gitlab shows me the repo url aus `[git@host:port]:....`