# Yii2 Advanced Template use model from frontend in console

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a long list of models in frontend. Some of these have functions that are required to be run in batch. For this console is fine.

I can include the models by copying over the code, however this is not a decent approach.

What Im looking for a way to **import models from the frontend submodule in console** command so I can make changes in one place.

**To clarify,**
the standard way of including

`use app\models\Mymodelname;`

in the console\model results in the following error

> 'Class 'app\models\Mymodelname' not found'

Comment: whats the problem you are having, cant you include those models using their namespace where ever they are placed, rather than copying the code to your console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use app\models\Mymodelname;
```

Have not worked with this include statement before. I prefer to use the frontend/backend as is. If I had to make a wild guess though, this looks for models within console. @app is an alias for current application.

Usually, I keep anything used by more than 1 application under common. As you pointed out, maintaining two copies of the same code is not a good practice.

Try using `frontend\models\Mymodelname` directly if moving to common is not an option

Comment: This works great, Why did I not think of it. Quite simple now that i see it, the complete solution includes changing the namespace of all fronternd models to from `app/models/modelname` to `frontend/models/modelname` and it suddenly is accessible from common or even backend.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have two separate applications, or could benefit from this, as you are already using submodules, but depending on your desire to separate concerns with some console commands this might be advantageous.

If you are using composer to manage your dependencies then you can create a separate repository in git, for example, and add a new dependency in your project which contains these common models.

Then, include your dependency in both projects. This introduces some troubles while developing since both apps share this dependency and it can be frustrating at times; I have shared common functionality between multiple interval laravel projects in this fashion with great success.

Currently you seem to be using submodules so this might require restructuring which could be difficult or impossible.

Another option if you want to keep to submodules is to keep common models at a higher level (not inside a submodule) so that you can import the models into both submodules and use them in both places. I shared common models between modules with yii 1.1.16 using this strategy over several years with much success.

Both options have their advantages so weigh carefully your desired outcomes. Feel free to ask for clarification.

[How to add private github repository as Composer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619393/how-to-add-private-github-repository-as-composer-dependency)

Comment: interesting concept. In yii advanced framework, common libraries can be added through the common models actually and this is workable without the complex solution you have mentioned. However this exposes the libraries to other modules as well which defeats the purpose of submodules. For an ideal solution, a submodule should stay within itself and be accessible from console .

Comment: @arkoak, it sounds like I was thinking something very different! In that case, if you just want use in a console command for example you might just need to include an import statement in your console config.

Perhaps you just lack importing the module's models like this?

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22359-how-to-access-module-model-from-within-the-console-app/

Answer (score 0):

`@app` is an alias of current running application.  It can be `frontend` or `backend` or `console`.  If you want to access model across applications, add it to `commen\models`.  Or change `app\models` to `frontend\models`.  That way, you can access `frontend` models on console.  Better way is moving it to `common\models`.