# How to add a new non-git private package/classes to a PHP application?

Tags: git, dependencies, composer-php, psr-4, psr-0

I have a small package with 6-7 files (i.e., main class, extending classes, interface, which can be viewed in [this link](https://github.com/emarcier/usco/tree/master/master/cron/equity)) and I'd like not to use `require_once` method to connect these classes together.

What might be the correct way to do so?

#### Attempts

I have tried to add them to `vendor` directory using [composer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619470/6553328).

```
composer require our-new-package-private
```

and

```
composer require our-new-package-private ~1.0.0
```

It returns an error:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                         
  Could not find a matching version of package equity-usco. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available i  
  n a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

#### Questions

- Do I need to first push the new package to a private GitHub repo, and then run:

  ```
   composer require our-new-package-private
  ```
- What might be the correct way to solve this problem and add a new private package or multiple scripts to a PHP-based app? Maybe, I should manually defined it in `autoload=>psr-0` or `autoload=>psr-4` in composer.json?

Comment: Is your package on a GitHub private repo ? Where is it ?

Comment: Currently it's not possible to use composer to get a package in a subfolder. https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/472.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's still not possible to create a composer package from a repository subfolder/ ([Github Issue](https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/472))

You can follow this [Packagist link](http://Publishing%20Packages) to create your own package.

> **Define Your Package**
>
> Put a file named composer.json at the root of your package's repository, containing this information:
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "your-vendor-name/package-name",
>     "description": "A short description of what your package does",
>     "require": {
>         "php": "^7.2",
>         "another-vendor/package": "1.*"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This is the strictly minimal information you have to give.
>
> For more details about package naming and the fields you can use to document your package better, see the about page.
>
> **Commit The File**
>
> Add the composer.json to your git or other VCS repository and commit it.
>
> **Publish It**
>
> Login or register on (the) site, then hit the submit button in the menu.
>
> [...]