# Composer: how to add private repository as a dependency?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an error for `composer install`:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Installation request for my/package dev-master -> satisfiable by my/package[dev-master].
> - my/package dev-master requires my/library dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
> - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

my/package composer.json content:

```
{
  "name": "my/package",
  "description": "package",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "my",
      "email": "my@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/my/"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.4.2",
    "my/library": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:my/library.git"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "my\\package\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

my/library composer.json content:

```
{
  "name": "my/library",
  "description": "a library",
  "license": "MIT",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "my",
      "email": "my@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/my/"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.4.2",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "mesilov/bitrix24-php-sdk": ">=0.7.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"

  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "my\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add private github repository as Composer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619393/how-to-add-private-github-repository-as-composer-dependency)

Comment: @YannickEich , I see no answer for my problem there

Comment: @YannickEich , both of 'my/library' and 'my/package' are private repositories. So, if 'my/package' is all right hence I think that ssh is ok. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Composer can't load repositories recursively:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md