# Composer won't clone from private git repository

Tags: php, git, gitlab, composer-php

I have a project that has a private gitlab repository as one of its dependencies. `composer.json` contains this:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.my_gitlab_domain.com:my/project.git"
        },
]
```

I **have** access to this repository via ssh, which means I can download it using `git clone` without requiring me to enter password or username. But when I try to install dependencies using `composer install` composer asks me for password for another user (which I don't have, my username is *ssagitov*):

```
- Syncing my/project (dev-master 620b5ef) into cache
git@git.my_gitlab_domain.com's password:
```

I tried to globally configure composer to use my password directly via:

```
composer config --global http-basic.git.my_gitlab_domain.com ssagitov my_password
```

That didn't work so I tried using

```
composer config --global gitlab-token.git.my_gitlab_domain.com my_personal_access_token
```

I also added git.my_gitlab_domain.com to `gitlab-domains`

```
composer config --global gitlab-domains git.my_gitlab_domain.com
```

As you can see none of this worked, so I'm out of ideas, how can I fix this?

Comment: Is this set of answers any use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619393/how-to-add-private-github-repository-as-composer-dependency

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it