# Composer is not installing the required dependencies of a forked library

Tags: github, composer-php

There is a library on Github, named `abc/xyz`.

I have forked the library to update its `composer.json`.

The `require` section of its `composer.json` is:

```json
{
   "require": {
       "xyz/abc": "^1.2",
   }
}
```

The`require` section of the forked version is:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "xyz/abc": "^2.4",
    }
}
```

When I do `composer require abc/xyz`, it also downloads and installs the `xyz/abc`
library.

But when I use the forked version and add the following to the `repositories` section of my root composer.json

```json
{
   "repositories": [
      {
         "type": "package",
           "package": {
               "name": "abc/xyz",
               "version": "1.2",
               "dist": {
                  "url": "url to zip folder of the forked version",
                  "type": "zip"
                },
            "type": "library"
           }
      }
   ]
}
```

Now when I do `composer require abc/xyz`, it only downloads and installs the actual package and not the `xyz/abc`.

I also tried with the `type: git` instead of `zip` and changed the `url` to the git version but the same results.

It only downloads and installs that dependency if I use it in the root composer.json

```
"type": "package",
                "package": {
                    "name": "abc/xyz",
                    "version": "1.2",
                    "dist": {
                       "url": "url to zip folder of the forked version",
                       "type": "zip"
                    },
                    "type": "library",
                    "require": {
                      "xyz/abc": "^2.4",
                    }
                }
```

Is this a standard way? OR I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: @yivi No that answer not worked form. They added autoload key to that package section. But still require to add the `require` key to the root composer.json.

Comment: Wo what type should I use then instead of a package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a repository of type `package`, the linked package's `composer.json` is not read.

The `package` type is meant to define the  `composer.json` file **inline**, mostly for packages that **do not support composer**.

From [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories):

> `package`: If you depend on a project that **does not have any support for Composer** whatsoever you can **define the package inline** using a `package` repository. You basically inline the composer.json object.

(**emphasis** mine)

If your package does support composer (e.g. includes a `composer.json` file that defines dependencies, autoloader, etc.), use type `vcs`.

To use a forked version, you simply add a repository that includes the forked version. Typically, for forks I simply depend on `dev-master`/`dev-main`, because the fork is not really published and only includes some hot-fixes that do not exist in the "main" package. Or `dev-whatever-branch-your-fixes-exist`.

Assuming your fork of `xyz/abc` is hosted on `https://github.com/ahmad/abc`, your root `composer.json` should be something like:

```json
{
   "repositories": [
      {
         "type": "vcs",
         "url": "https://github.com/ahmad/abc"
      }
   ],
   "require": {
      "xyz/abc": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

(Just added the relevant parts, obviously this doesn't mean you have to delete the rest of your root `composer.json` file, just change the appropriate bits)

Comment: If I use type `vcs` and provide a url? Do I need to run composer require abc/xyz? If yes, it again downloads the actual library instead of the forked version.

Comment: You need to add a repository `type: vcs` that points to the github repo that holds your forked version. On your `require` section, change the version that you depend on from whatever specific version you had to `dev-master` or `dev-main` (or whatever branch holds your changes to the forked library). This works, I do it all the time.

Comment: Yes this worked, the only problem is now that it requires token since it is a private repository and you cannot change the visibility settings of a forked version

Comment: That's a different issue, out of scope for this question. Questions like this one ([How to add private github repository as Composer dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40619393/1426539)) would be a good starting point.

Comment: Since as it is **"it works"**, I'd say the question is answered. Now the what's left for you to solve is how to access a private repo. As long as you can do `git clone` on the target machine, you can use the above. If you can't, then you have another issue. But that's usually solvable by adding specific tokens or keys with read-only permissions where needed.